# Google Cloud: deny access to a single file in a given bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

Supposing I have:

- a Google Cloud Storage bucket `bucketxyz` and two users groups: `group1` and `group2`;
- an additional third group `allusers` that includes all the users among `group1` and `group2`.

And then:

- An IAM policy for `bucketxyz` that grants *read only* access to `allusers` and *read/write* (but no ownership, to avoid files deletion) to `group1`.

Consider also two files for `bucketxyz`: `file_shared.txt` and `file_resticted.txt` and these two scenarios:

1. `file_shared.txt` can be written by someone in `group1` but also
   accessible by users in `group2` - ***Done just by using the IAM policy above.***
2. `file_restricted.txt` can be written and accessible ONLY by users in `group1`.

Is it possible to implement the scenario #2 by using dedicated **ACL rule** for `file_restricted.txt` in `bucketxyz`? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3):

Permissions in IAM are concentric, and there is no notion of a "deny" - as described in the [IAM Policy Hierarchy documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#policy_hierarchy), "Child policies cannot restrict access granted at the parent".

To achieve a case where `group1` and `group2` could access `file_shared.txt` but only `group2` could access `file_restricted.txt`, you would need grant access per-object to `group1` and `group2`.  Alternatively, you could grant `group2` read/write access at the `bucketxyz` level, and grant read access per-object to `group1`.

Comment: Recently Google Cloud brought the concept of IAM Deny